# Draw perpendicular line of fixed length at a point of another line

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I have two points A (10,20) and B (15,30). The points generate a line AB. I need to draw a perpendicular line, CD, on point B with a length of 6 (each direction 3 units) in Python.

I already have some properties of line AB using the following code:

```
from scipy import stats
x = [10,15]
y = [20,30]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

How can I calculate the location of C and D. I need their X and Y value. 
[image]

The value of C and D will be used for accomplishing another objective using the Shapely library.

Comment: Are you asking a maths question: how to calculate points `C` and `D`?

Comment: python code would be good but I can also use the math equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `slope` is the slope of AB, then the slope of CD is `-1/slope`. This is equal to vertical change over horizontal change: `dy/dx = -1/slope`. This gives that `dx = -slope*dx`. And by Pythagorean Theorem, you have `3**2 = dy**2+dx**2`. Substitute for `dx`, and you get

`3**2 = (-slope*dy)**2+dy**2`
`3**2 = (slope**2 + 1)*dy**2`
`dy**2 = 3**2/(slope**2+1)`
`dy = math.sqrt(3**2/(slope**2+1))`

Then you can get `dx = -slope*dy`. Finally, you can use `dx` and `dy` to get C and D. So the code would be:

```
import math
dy = math.sqrt(3**2/(slope**2+1))
dx = -slope*dy
C[0] = B[0] + dx
C[1] = B[1] + dy
D[0] = B[0] - dx
D[1] = B[1] - dy
```

(Note that although `math.sqrt` returns only one number, in general there is a positive and negative square root. C corresponds to the positive square root, and D to the negative).

Answer (score 19):

Since you are interested in using Shapely, the easiest way to get the perpendicular line that I can think of, is to use [`parallel_offset`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.parallel_offset) method to get two parallel lines to AB, and connect their endpoints:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

a = (10, 20)
b = (15, 30)
cd_length = 6

ab = LineString([a, b])
left = ab.parallel_offset(cd_length / 2, 'left')
right = ab.parallel_offset(cd_length / 2, 'right')
c = left.boundary[1]
d = right.boundary[0]  # note the different orientation for right offset
cd = LineString([c, d])
```

[image]

And the coordinates of CD:

```
>>> c.x, c.y
(12.316718427000252, 31.341640786499873)
>>> d.x, d.y
(17.683281572999746, 28.658359213500127)
```

Comment: I don't know how fast it is, but I like the simplicity of that solution.

Comment: aweeeeeesomme!)

Answer (score 2):

You probably should use vectors to calculate the position of the points.

- create the `vector AB`
- calculate its `normalized perpendicular`
- add or subtract 3 times this to `B`

with the help of a simple, reusable `Vector class`, the calculation is trivial, and reads like English:

Find the points perpendicular to `AB` at distance `3` from point `B`:
`P1 = B + (B-A).perp().normalized() * 3`
`P2 = B + (B-A).perp().normalized() * 3`

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    def dot(self, other):
        return self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y
    def norm(self):
        return self.dot(self)**0.5
    def normalized(self):
        norm = self.norm()
        return Vector(self.x / norm, self.y / norm)
    def perp(self):
        return Vector(1, -self.x / self.y)
    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'


A = Vector(10, 20)
B = Vector(15, 30)

AB = B - A  
AB_perp_normed = AB.perp().normalized()
P1 = B + AB_perp_normed * 3
P2 = B - AB_perp_normed * 3

print(f'Point{P1}, and Point{P2}')
```

**output:**

```
Point(17.683281572999746, 28.658359213500127), and Point(12.316718427000252, 31.341640786499873)
```

Comment: What happens for A = Vector(10, 20)
B = Vector(15, 20) your AB.perf() gives {...,y:Nan} in javascript.How to handle when y does not change?

Answer (score 0):

If we have a line parallel to x-axis or y-axis, then we can add the following two methods to the class Vector.

```
def perptoy(self):
    return Vector(1, 0)
def perptox(self):
    return Vector(1, -10000) // any big number will do instead of -inf

AB = B - A  
if (A.y == B.y):
   AB_perp_normed = AB.perptox().normalized();
elif (A.x == B.x):
   AB_perp_normed = AB.perptoy().normalized();
else:
   AB_perp_normed = AB.perp().normalized();
```

And the rest follows the same as in the earlier post.